# Segfault in R while installing packages with C code

Tags: r, linux

What to fix to install packages that depend on C with R?
The package ps is an example it happens with many more, such as sys, diffobj, xfun, etc.

```
> install.packages("ps")
Installing package into ‘/home/roland/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ps_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 110708 bytes (108 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 108 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ps’ ...
** package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -Wall px.c -o px
make: *** [Makevars:11: px] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ps’
* removing ‘/home/roland/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ps’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuD2CLF/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ps") :
  installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 with r-base and r-base-core installed via apt-get.

Extracting the package's .tar.gz and running the gcc command by itself doesn't result in a segfault.

And the version output:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock
```

Answer (score 0):

That really shouldn't happen. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (but running the R 4.0.3 deb via CRAN and Launchpad).  We should be able to sort this out.

(As an aside you can also simply rely on pre-built packages as there are over 4500 of them.  But if you don't even get the basic R binary then that may be a step too far.)

(As another aside we have a friendly and low-volume mailing list r-sig-debian for Debian based distributions, Ubuntu included, at the usual R mailing list server. It's good for these question.)

On a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 system (running via Docker container `ubuntu:20.04`) I just installed `r-base-dev` and then installed `ps` without issues:

```
root@e1c8cac32650:/# Rscript -e 'install.packages("ps")'
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ps_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 110708 bytes (108 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 108 KB

* installing *source* package 'ps' ...
** package 'ps' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -Wall px.c -o px
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-common.c -o api-common.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c extra.c -o extra.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dummy.c -o dummy.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c error-codes.c -o error-codes.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c posix.c -o posix.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-posix.c -o api-posix.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c linux.c -o linux.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-linux.c -o api-linux.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o ps.so init.o api-common.o common.o extra.o dummy.o error-codes.o posix.o api-posix.o linux.o api-linux.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-ps/00new/ps
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (ps)

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpRhmQqd/downloaded_packages'
root@e1c8cac32650:/#
```

*Edit:* As it is not so well known, here is my current preferred alternatice.  Using Ubuntu 20.04 with [bspm](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=bspm) setup along with the aforementioned PPA, we just do `install.packages("ps")` and get the corresponding *binary*. This is a very convenient alternative that only takes about one minute to set up.

```
edd@rob:~/git/r-ci/docs(master)$ docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-bspm:20.04
root@0456aca56464:/# Rscript -e 'install.packages("ps")'
Loading required package: utils
Tracing function "install.packages" in package "utils"
Install system packages as root...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease [18.1 kB]                                                                                                                              
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/edd/r-4.0/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [643 kB]                                                                                                                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter4.0/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [466 kB]                                                                                                                               
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal/main Sources [1745 kB]                                                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                              
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                                                                         
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [126 kB]                                                                                                                           
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.4 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [850 kB]                                                                                                                                
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [871 kB]                                                                                                                            
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [4248 B]                                                                                                                          
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [837 kB]                                                                                                                    
Fetched 5913 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal/main amd64 r-cran-ps amd64 1.4.0-1cran1.2004.0 [239 kB]                                                                                          
Fetched 239 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                      
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-ps.
(Reading database ... 20576 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-ps_1.4.0-1cran1.2004.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-ps (1.4.0-1cran1.2004.0) ...
Setting up r-cran-ps (1.4.0-1cran1.2004.0) ...
root@0456aca56464:/#
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried the following, install the latest ubuntu package from the cloud.r-project repository by following: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/ Unfortunately I still get the same error. I'll try the mailing list tomorrow.

Comment: We need to backtrack and see what if anything you may have hosed.  Can you compile `gcc -o hw helloworld.c` where `helloworld.c` is the usual four line with a `printf()` as _e.g._ [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-hello-world-program/) or in many other places?

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. Yes I can:

$ gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -Wall px.c -o px

Works fine.

Comment: I pinned down the problem. It's the inclusion of the "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" directory in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. 
Example: 
```roland@MiX:~/wb1/ps/src$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You should not have the problem in the first place. `ps` is a vanilla package in good standing [which builds everywhere](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ps.html), and also on my 20.04 system.  You may inadvertently have hosed some component of your system.

Comment: Note that between your comments of Nov 27 and now you appear to also have changed the R version from 3.6.3 to 4.0.3 as is revealed from the include paths.  That can require package rebuilds.  There were a lot of blog posts about upgrading to R 4.0.*; I think I even recorded a short video.  Look for older blog posts from April for hints.